# Declare the Spanish Inquisition

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

The starting point is before times of old,
On the record in Defensor Fidei,
The old one in front of the doctor told,
Of a proof not for P and in NP,
Given by the Saint's follower before
the Phaeton, adorned fittingly in gold.

Hint

> A flutter, a chance,
>  one or nothing, on the fly,
>  still; we are centered.

Comment: NOBODY expects the Spanish Inquisition!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Along similar lines to Gareth's answer, I think the answer is

> the VOWELS.

*The starting point is before times of old,*

> The starting point of the alphabet is **A**, which comes before "BC" used to denote times of old.

*On the record in Defensor Fidei,*

> After a record or CD comes the letter **E**, which is also "in" Defensor Fidei or DF.

*The old one in front of the doctor told,*

> The old (Roman) one is **I**, which appears in front of the letters JKL, which sound like Jekyll, a doctor.

*Of a proof not for P and in NP,*

> Removing the letters "for P" from "proof" gives **O**, which is also the letter "in" NP.

*Given by the Saint's follower before*
*the Phaeton,*

> The follower of a Saint or St. is **U**, which also comes before VW, and apparently there was a Volkswagen Phaeton.

*adorned fittingly in gold.*

> The vowels fit snugly between A and U, which two letters form the chemical abbreviation for gold.

Title:

> "Declare" -> VOW; "the Spanish" -> EL. Very clever indeed!

Thanks to @MOehm and @indubitablee for help with some of the clues.

---

**Feedback section**

Awesome riddle! This is just the sort of thing I might have come up with myself - cluing a very simple and basic final solution by building up other things around it and then cluing *them* in turn, in a way that makes it extremely clear when you've got the right solution (as all good riddles should be). I like the way hardly a word is wasted, and cluing everything twice makes the answer even more self-confirming. Ironically, while the hint actually helped me (seeing "we are centered" and then looking at "Defensor Fidei" and "NP" made something click), it was the only thing I wasn't able to match properly to the solution. The OP explained that it's meant to be:

> BAT, BET, BIT, BOT, BUT.

Comment: The "old one" is probably a Roman one. Not sure about the E, but there are several E sounds in Fidei Defensor, depending on how you pronounce the Is.

Comment: Yes and +1 - the second one comes after a record. For 3rd @MOehm +1. Fourth see also Gareth's ans.

Comment: Oh, the record is a Compact Disc!

Comment: @MOehm Ooh, clever. Edited.

Comment: @Tom Awesome riddle! I love how everything fits together so neatly. (Ironically, the only thing I don't get at all is the hint.)

Comment: Thanks Rand! The hint clues the words r13 (ong, org, ...)

Comment: Oh, and "Declare the Spanish" is VOW EL.

Comment: Yes @MOehm ! (more especially declare ~ avow)

Comment: So it all amounts to A Vowel Quest(ion)?

Comment: Yes @MOehm, also appreciate your top comments.

Comment: "adorned fittingly in gold": is that because all the other vowels are sandwiched between A and U and Au = gold on the periodic table?

Comment: @indubitablee - yes, thanks for completing the final piece +1

Answer (score 8):

**Partial answer**

First of all, the title.

> I think "Declare" is just a homophone indicator. Then "the Spanish" -> EL -> L, and "Inquisition" -> WHY -> Y. So the title is hinting at something to do with the -LY suffix. (Maaaaybe.)

I initially thought that this was describing

> the alphabet.

In comments OP indicates that this isn't quite right, but *something* of the kind seems clearly to be going on, as we'll see.

The starting point is before times of old,

> A BC

On the record in Defensor Fidei,

> This Latin term is almost always actually given as "Fidei Defensor" and abbreviated FD or FID DEF. Here, I assume it indicates DF with something inside it. An EP is a record, but maybe an E can be, or can signify "on the record"? That would yield DEF; but perhaps something else is going on here. (DLOGF? DLPF? ...)

The old one in front of the doctor told,

> noneuclideanisms suggests in comments that "the doctor told" might be JKL which sounds a bit like "Jekyll". Seems plausible. (TwoBitOperation suggests further that "told" might indicate putting "Hi" in front, but I don't buy that.) "The Old One" is what Einstein sometimes called (his rather nonstandard conception of) God, but I don't know whether that's relevant here. MOehm suggested that instead H = age = old (which seems a bit of a stretch) and then I = one, in which case this would give us HIJKL.

Of a proof not for P and in NP,

> If we take PROOF and remove the letters of FOR P, we get O, and if we put that in NP we get NOP. Perhaps "Of a" at the start has some further significance, perhaps not.

Given by the Saint's follower before

> "Saint" seems like ST. Perhaps "follower" could yield "queuer" and hence QR, though that's a bit far-fetched.

the Phaeton adorned fittingly in gold.

> There was a Volkswagen Phaeton, suggesting that we get VW here.

So we seem to have, at least,

> ABC, maybe DEF or something like it, maybe something involving JKL, NOP, (QR?)ST, and VW.

OP also says in comments that

> each element is clued twice

but I'm having trouble seeing

> where there's space for much in the way of further clues, if the above is anything like correct -- and, if not, why so much of it seems to be the way it is. Leftover bits after accounting for the tersest possible indications of what's above seem to be: the is before? / on the record / the old one in front of / of a / given by the / the adorned fittingly in gold. Letters possibly missing from the alphabetical sequence seem to be: E G (HI?) M (QR?) U XYZ.

Comment: Perhaps "the doctor" refers to Dr. Jekyll?

Comment: Removed 'I' from the title and added a comma

Comment: @noneuclideanisms "The doctor told" could be "Hi, Jekyll" -> HI JKL

Comment: I think that the "starting point" is just a decorative phrase in the poem and that all letters from B to T go into Au, followed by VW and leaving XYZ unaccounted for. I thought that the "old one" could be H (which sounds a little bit like age) and I. That would leave the G and M without explanation.

Comment: "Adorned in gold" is something from the Bible, actually it's E'Z'ekiel 16. Perhaps you'll need this Z.

Comment: @MOehm That's a nice idea. But doesn't it require "before" to apply to everything except the Phaeton? If so, then my explanation of QR doesn't work. Perhaps something else does, though.

Comment: Oh, and how do you explain why "The starting point is *before* times of old"?

Comment: Well, I probably didn't think that through.

Comment: Right idea - there's a different answer - each element of which is clued twice.

Comment: The title gives a full description of this puz - one part of your explanation is used.

Comment: So near and yet so far ... see my answer :-)